# Access the state in an action in redux

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

Many links and tutorials advice to group the logic in action creators in order to simplify the reducer logic.

Imagine a simple (normalized) state:

```
const initialState = {
  parent: {
    allIds: [0],
    byId: {
      0: {
        parentProperty: `I'm the parent`,
        children: [1, 2]
      }
    }
  },
  children: {
    allIds: [1, 2],
    byId: {
      1: {
        childrenProperty: `I'm the children`
      },
      2: {
        childrenProperty: `I'm the children`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would now delete the parent. Since only the parent refers to the children, I would also delete the children too.

I imagine a action creator like this:

```
function deleteParents(parentId) {
  return {type: 'DELETE_PARENT', payload: {parentId}};
}
```

and

```
function deleteChild(childId) {
   return {type: 'DELETE_CHILD', payload: {childId}};
}
```

For now, to manage this case I do something like this (with redux-thunk)

```
function deleteParentAndChildren(parentId) {
  return (dispatch, getState) {
    const childrenIds = myChildrenSelector(getState(), parentId);
    const deleteChildrenActions = childrenIds.map(deleteChild);
    const deleteParentAndChildrenAction = batchActions([
      deleteParents(parentId),
      ...deleteChildrenActions
    ], 'DELETE_PARENT_AND_CHILDREN');
    dispatch(deleteParentAndChildrenAction);
  }
}
```

In that way, I compose little action into big one, and the reducer logic is very simple because it only consist to delete a key in an object.

Conversely, I don't like to use redux-thunk (used to async actions) just to get the state (and this is considered as anti pattern).

How do you guys manage this type of problems ?
Does a tool like redux-sage may help ?

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you are trying to achieve, please? So you would like a way to delete a parent and all corresponding children?

Comment: exactly, so sorry to be unclear. I would also keep little (and composable) actions

Comment: Have you considered reevaluating your data structure? I would consider having the parent key and the children key as arrays, with objects inside. Each object has its structure with a reference ID. A parent object could have a children array containing the ids of the related children.

I would have an async action using redux-thunk to call the removal of the parent, the final action call for a successful deletion could then trigger another async action to delete any children with the ref id related to the parent that was removed.

Answer (score 0):

The problematic you seem to have seems fairly common and if your application is a bit sophisticated I would suggest using [redux-orm](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm) which is a bit hard to understand and then integrate but once set up it just abstract you all the hard relationship work between your entities.

Answer (score 0):

I opine differently here. The way I would do it is, I would delete child while deleting parent but not y dispatching child_delete action. When you create new state while deleting parent in reducer, at that time, you can access the children referred by that parent, and remove those as well from state.

Also, if you still want to dispatch actions separately, you can pass childids from component to action. From that action, you can dispatch two different actions, deleting parent and chilren ids.

-----------  EDIT -------

```
// The initial application state
const initialState = {
  parent: {
    allIds: [0],
    byId: {
      0: {
        parentProperty: `I'm the parent`,
        children: [1, 2]
      }
    }
  },
  children: {
    allIds: [1, 2],
    byId: {
      1: {
        childrenProperty: `I'm the children`
      },
      2: {
        childrenProperty: `I'm the children`
      }
    }
  }
}

export default function batchManagement(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'DELETE_PARENT':  //assuming action.deleteParents = [0]
      //Here you have access to state, so you can change parents and children as well, and create a totally new state
    case 'DELETE_CHILDREN':
      //Return a new object for state
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But to find the children Ids, I need the state. That means I need redux-thunk as a work around (even to do synchronouse action).

Comment: Hi @Epitouille, I guess you didn't get me right. When you right a reducer method, you get access to state. Please see my edited answer

Comment: Oh Yes I didn't get you right. The problem with your option is my full reducer is: `combineReducer({parent, children});` So I never access the full state of my app. I only get a slice. :)

Comment: My bad. Didn't think of that option. Let me figure out what else can be done.

Well in that case, do you have access to children ids referred by parent in component. If you have the childrenids, you can separately dispatch parent_delete and children_delete from component

Comment: For now, I use the method with redux-thunk described in the original question. May not be the best solution but it works well. The other problem comes if children have children (grand-children). I can only have the grand children ids if I resolve the children. In all case, I'll need the full state somewhere. The best solution is probably the @guillaumepotier answer and use and ORM.